# Loop through array in search for elements with certain attributes - with as short/concise code as possible

Tags: ruby, arrays

My **check_processors** method should go through an array of processors (provided by the **processor_list** argument) and output a new array, containing the same processors.

The **processor_list** argument is either *nil* or an array of processors, e.g.:

```
    [
      <Processor _id: 5158713883c336812100007f, _type: nil, created_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, updated_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, name: "my_mapping_processor", value: {"something"=>{"something_else"}}, type: "mapping", order: 0>,
      <Processor _id: 5158713883c3368121000080, _type: nil, created_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, updated_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, name: "my_presentation_processor", value: {"something"=>{"something_else"}}, type: "presentation", order: 1>,
      <Processor _id: 5348143r83c93641210d0080, _ty...
    ]
```

The **check_processors** method should verify that 2 specific processors (recognized by the *type* attribute of a processor) exists. If no processor with *type* == "mapping" is found, **create_mapping_processor** should it. Or if no processor with *type* == "presentation" is found, **create_presentation_processor** should create it.

The code below works, but the job it is doing is so simple that it must be achievable with less code.

```
    def check_processors(processor_list = nil)

      processors = []

      if processor_list == nil
        mapping_processor = create_mapping_processor
        presentation_processor = create_presentation_processor
        processors.push(mapping_processor)
        processors.push(presentation_processor)
      else
        mapping_processor_exists = false
        presentation_processor_exists = false
        processor_list.each do |processor|
          processors.push(processor)
          mapping_processor_exists = true if processor.type == "mapping"
          presentation_processor_exists = true if processor.type == "presentation"
        end

        if mapping_processor_exists == false
          mapping_processor = create_mapping_processor
          processors.push(mapping_processor)
        end

        if presentation_processor_exists == false
          presentation_processor = create_presentation_processor
          processors.push(presentation_processor)
        end
      end
      processors #=> [<Processor _id: 5158713883c336812100007f, _type: nil, created_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, updated_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, name: "my_mapping_processor", value: {"something"=>{"something_else"}}, type: "mapping", order: 0>, <Processor _id: 5158713883c3368121000080, _type: nil, created_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, updated_at: 2013-03-31 17:24:08 UTC, name: "my_presentation_processor", value: {"something"=>{"something_else"}}, type: "presentation", order: 1>, <Processor _id: 5348143r83c93641210d0080, _ty...]
    end

    def create_mapping_processor
      mapping_processor = Processor.new(:name => "my_mapping_processor", :value => {"something"=>{"something_else"}}, :type => "mapping", :order => 0)
      mapping_processor
    end

    def create_presentation_processor
      presentation_processor = Processor.new(:name => "my_presentation_processor", :value => {"something"=>{"something_else"}}, :type => "presentation", :order => 1)
      presentation_processor
    end
```

Comment: just give some sample inputs and outputs you want.

Comment: Hi @iAmRubuuu. I have added a sample output to the post (2nd last line in the code).

Comment: You seem to have some variables and methods with the same name in the code? If nothing else, it's confusing to read. Also, your 4-step psuedo code at the top could do with expanding: If *what* is TRUE or FALSE for steps 2 and 3?

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 Rewrite your code, or your question will be down voted. As Neil said there is an ambiguity on what create_presentaion_processor is (var/method)

Comment: @NeilSlater I assume create_presentation_proccessor is a method, which return Proccessor object and takes an option param which can be bool.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comments. I realize the post lacked sufficient consistency in use of names. I have re-written the entire post now. Please let me know if it needs further improvement.